# Remove XML Node, including children if present, via text editor

Tags: xml, notepad++

I'd like to remove a tag/node entirely (including children) in notepad++ (or other FOSS text editor) that may/may not have children, and possibly grandchildren, etc... I've tried regular expressions (noted on a few other SO Questions) but having trouble with the multiline aspect of these nodes/tags.

```
<exampleTag id="blah" name="bob">
    <childTag possible="element" />
    <moreChildren>
        <evenAnotherLevel />
    </moreChildren>
</exampleTag>
```

It is funny that both textWrangler and notepad++ can collapse a node for easier reading:

[image]

Which makes it easy to delete the whole thing manually, but this won't work for a file with potentially 10000s or more of these tags. Is there a tool/plugin out there that can do this? Right now I break out node.js to get this done, but that isn't a solution for laymen.

Comment: Simple task using XSLT (the language to manipulate XML) which is an XML file itself. Do you have an XSLT processor available? Any general purpose language (C#, Java, Python, PHP, Perl, VB)?

Answer (score 1):

On text editors such as BBEdit, TextWrangler and others that use PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions), you can set the "Magic Dot" option (allows . to match \r and \n) by putting at the front of your search (?s)

Also, when looking for the closing XML tag like  be sure to use non-greedy searches by using ? after any pattern like .* that could otherwise match the end tag.

So for example in TextWrangler you can search for

```
(?s)^    <exampleTag code="[0-9]*" name="[0-9]* - .*?</exampleTag>$.
```

and replace it with nothing. This would find every <exampleTag starting 4 spaces after a newline with a numeric code and with a name containing a sequence of digits - anything (non-greedy) until the end </exampleTag> followed by a newline. The final . at the end assures that the newline will be deleted too. (On Windows you might need two dots for the cr-lf.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT transformation directly from Notepad++. So, you need to remove specific nodes with all the inner XML inside. Here is a  template you can use or adjust to your needs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="exampleTag"/> <!-- The tags we want to remove are here -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, save this as an *.xslt file on the disk. Then, open your XML in Notepad++ and go to *Plugins* -> *XML Tools* -> *XSL Transformation*.  Provide the path to your XSLT file:

[image]

And click **Transform**.